# How to share the Workspace for Android SDK between Windows and Ubuntu?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm sharing one workspace between those two systems, and as I'm developing for Android I need Android SDK, which is in Windows in `D:/Android/sdk`, on Ubuntu it's different path.

How can I make it to switch automatically at Windows to D:/.. and on Ubuntu to home/...?

Because now each time I switch systems, I have to point eclipse to the SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't share file system, use a sane source code version system, like git or subversion. Because you should have that anyway, even if you work on your source yourself.
It's problems sharing projects with different versions of Eclipse or any IDE as it is, so doing that between two OS with different syntax and semantics would only drive you insane. Been there, tried that.

Comment: Thanks, I followed your advice and used Bitbucket (as I want to have my repos private) and EGit for an Eclipse. Works like charm. Thx

Answer (score 0):

You have to options:

1. The first one and the best is to share a *partition* between Ubuntu and Windows.

   In that partitions you can create a project from one system and then modify that project from the other OS.

   NOTE: this partitions should have a compatible file system (recommended: NTFS)
2. Also you can work with a project saved on your Windows partition (as you're now). But this is not recommended because you will find incompatibility's issues.

IMO you should proceed with the first option

Comment: I'm doing it right now, but my questions is about how to share SDK, as Eclipse keeps path to it in workspace (.metadata), and in my case on each system it is different (so I have to go to options and manually correct it).

Comment: Yeah, that is part of the undesired effects. Personally, I not recommend to modify a project with two different platforms.